# "I am halfway to you" or "I am halfway from you"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Q."How far are you from me: (over the phone talking to friend who is about to reach his friend's home)
I know I could say, "I am 7 miles from you".

But if I use word "halfway" then should I say? I am halfway to you or I am halfway from you.

And does "I am halfway from you" mean I am heading towards a specific location or I am heading away from specific location?

Comment: "I'm halfway there." (_There_ referring to the destination of a journey.) Possibly "I'm halfway to your house", but not '"to you".

Comment: By "halway" do you mean "halfway"?  It looks like a typo, but you've repeated it six times.

Comment: @James K. My mistake. Yes it is "halfway". It was a typo. I am correcting it now.

Comment: @Kate Bunting do you not think another possibility could be "I am halfway from your house"

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me. _Halfway_ here means 'I've covered half the distance **from** [my point of departure] **to** your house' - it doesn't make sense to speak of being halfway from the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I use word "halfway" then should I say? I am halfway to you or I am halfway from you.

You could say either. However, because "to" implies the direction of motion, it is clearer, and I think that it would be more common, as well.

Note that "halfway" is vague unless the total distance is mentioned explicitly or can be inferred from context.

> And does "I am halfway from you" mean I am heading towards a specific location or I am heading away from specific location?

It could mean either. (For example: "I'm heading to your location but am still 30 miles away from you." "I've left your location and am now 30 miles away from you.") This is possible because the preposition "from" is often used to indicate distance. (It could even be used when there is no motion. For example, "San Francisco is 350 miles from Los Angeles." )

Answer (score 1):

Probably "to you" but you wouldn't need to specify any "to" or "from".  In order for "halfway" to makes sense, there needs to be an understood journey from a known starting point.  So you would just say "I'm halfway"

> Where are you now?
>
> Well, I'm about halfway, so I should be with you in an hour.